# Keep the whole page (the horizonal scrollbar position) center when zooming in

Tags: css

I know how to keep elements center but now I want the whole page center (i.e. the horizonal scrollbar should be in the middle) when zooming in. Now the scrollbar is at the very left end when zooming in.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#p {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.c1,
.c2,
.c3 {
  margin: 1rem;
  min-width: 15rem;
  height: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.c1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.c2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.c3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="p">
  <div class="c1">
    aaa
  </div>
  <div class="c2">
    bbb
  </div>
  <div class="c3">
    ccc
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see when it zooms in to a certain level the red `div` will be out of the view and cannot be reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This impossible with only CSS. You can consider using Javascript.

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#p");
const centerEl = document.querySelector(".center-element");

container.scrollLeft = centerEl.offsetLeft + centerEl.offsetWidth / 2 - container.offsetWidth / 2;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#p {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  /* removed:
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
  */
  overflow-x: scroll;  /* added. so that it does not affect the whole page. */
}

.c1,
.c2,
.c3 {
  margin: 1rem;
  min-width: 15rem;
  height: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.c1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.c2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.c3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="p">
  <div class="c1">
    aaa
  </div>
  <div class="c2 center-element">
    bbb
  </div>
  <div class="c3">
    ccc
  </div>
</div>
```